# Is there any backside to creating a softlink instead of the various default folders inside /home?

Tags: linux, gnome, symlink, home

I'd like to know if there are any backsides to replacing the various default folders (specifically: `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Music`, `Pictures`, and `Videos`) with symlinks to a different drive? Basically, I have two SSDs inside my PC: one for the OS; one for my personal files. I have all my personal stuff on `/mnt/personal/Documents` etc. so I was wondering if it's safe to just, say, `rmdir ~/Documents` (it's empty, anyway) and just do `ln -s /mnt/personal/Documents ~/Documents`.

Are there any drawbacks/things I should be aware of?

I'm using GNOME.

Comment: Don't know how well it works to softlink them but you could probably just reconfigure the location of those [XDG user directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_user_directories).

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one downside I am aware of. Softlinks are just files themselves. So when a program reads a softlink, it reads the file containing it, sees that it's a softlink and then opens the file specified inside the link file. This effectively results in a doubling of the number of disk operations performed in/on those files.

So, for example, copying a lot of small files might take nearly (but not quite) twice as long while the difference won't be noticeable for large files since the data transfer and not the opening of the file is the limiting factor for large files.

Comment: Many programs use `openat`, which will only do the symlink resolution once. I'd especially expect that (as an example from the question) a music application would use openat() and not do the symlink resolution for the library base path each time.